# file_get_contents оптимизация кода php sql

Tags: php, файлы, оптимизация, вывод

На странице в коде есть запрос на получение всего. В т ч и  путь к картинке $ava_way.
Но на странице такж есть вызов

```
<img src="/show.php?wsh=6&uid=8736" width = "150" height = "150">
```

В скрипте вывода картинки есть обращение к бд для получение пути к картинке и ее вывода при помощи file_get_contents.

Краткий код вывода картинки:

```
select ava_way from ava where uid_ava=8736
...
...
...
@$file = file_get_contents($ava_way . "M");
    //2016-12-27 Переписал чтобы в тбл было ОДНО поле
    //а имена формируються в скрипте
    echo $file;
    exit;
```

**$ava_way . "M"** - означает **миниатюра** картинки.

---

Чтобы избавиться от "лишнего" запроса, который есть в

```
"/show.php?wsh=6&uid=8736"
```

я написал функцию:

```
function shava($ava_way){
 $file = file_get_contents($ava_way . "M");
 //2016-12-27 Переписал чтобы в тбл было ОДНО поле
 //а имена формируються в скрипте
 //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 echo $file;
 //exit;
}
```

но она выводит в браузер поток байт, а не картинку. Можно ли убрать запрос к бд. А картинку выводить функцией? И как правильно сделать чтобы вывод был картинкой, а не потоком байт?

---

Без shava() все абсолютно четко работает. Вопрос касается **ОПТИМИЗАЦИИ** (исключению лишнего запроса к бд).

---

```
$ava_way это ../ava/d/Xj/gfepPSnulL0209056001482870188
```

уСТАНОВКА заголовков

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

особо не помогает.

*Пока редактировал вопрос кажись уже понял что нужно сделать.*

**upd**
Наверное нужно создать скрипт который каким-то загадочным способом будет получать путь к картинке и ... НО такой способ противоречит принципу выдачи картинок по скрипту. незн. сейчас буду пробовать... Протестировал я это - всё-таки останется этот "лишний" запрос.

---

Про собак и ошибки: Именно в этом участке кода ВСЕГДА будет собака. Саму ошибку я не обрабатываю. Ведь если у пользователя нет аватара, то он не сможет получить доступ к элементам управления и не сможет загрузить новую аву. Само собой разумеется, что после регистрации будут какие-то дефолтные аватарки.

Comment: ваш вопрос бессмыслен по 2м причинам, 1 неизвестно, что вы передаете в $ava_way? кроме того зачем вы его в кавычки засадили в функции получения файла. 2 причина потому, что непонятно работают ли у вас заголовки, для начала надо было бы проверить на известной картинке, что она точно выдается и что она точно jpg может стоит получить exif значение хотя-бы и передать правильный заголовок?

Comment: я упростил. сейчас отредактирую

Comment: file_get_contents("$ava_way" . "M") зачем кавычки в "$ava_way", потом вы специально отключили вывод ошибки вот этой конструкцией @$file и ведет ли данный путь к реальному файлу?

Comment: не заглушайте ошибки символом собаки, это сильно затрудняет поиск ошибок

Comment: УЖЕ ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАЛ

Comment: Ну и вообще для справки, можно перекодировать в base64 и выводить вот так <img src="data:image/png;base64,нобор_байт">

Comment: несколько смущает, что заголовки `image/jpeg` вы точно уверены, что там всегда Jpeg  у вас?

Comment: на прием (ВО ВСЕМ ПРОЭКТЕ) только gif png jpeg bmp графика. гиф конвертится в пнж (с сохранением прозрачности). бмп конвертится в джпег. Я експериментально выяснил что header не влияет на вывод пнж и джпега. По поводу перекодировать...незнаю нужно и так попробовать, хотя я сомневаюсь. И  вот еще что: Я header посылаю только при показе оригинала картинки. Миниатюра показывается и без header. ну теперь а суть вопроса понятна? Дело не в ошибках, а в оптимизации.

Comment: ИЛИ я очень мутно и дотошно заморачиваюсь из-за каждого запроса и каждой не идеальной строчки кода?